# Variable extrusion strength based on "depthmap" image

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm a Blender beginner and already made some progress with the help of this forum. I'm designing vector graphics in Illustrator and export them (DXF) to Blender.

I learned how to use Geometry Nodes to take the 2D Curves and give them thickness and extrude them.

[image: Extrusion of curves]

Also learned how to vary the extrusion height with sine functions etc.

Now I'm searching for some more control, e.g. by having two layers for my input graphics:

1. the vector paths that should be extruded
2. a "depthmap" with a black&white image to control the extrusion strength/height

[image: input-images]

Is there a way to archive this with Geometry Nodes? (I want to 3D print the results)

Thank you!

Comment: I would say the main problem is, you need geometry to apply the depth map to. There are some leaf veins, okay, but just looking at the outline for example: where are the points covering the leaf area inbetween to be affected by the grey values there? You need some kind of grid mesh to have at least a few vertices being manipulated by the depth map. But there is no grid fill or remesh in _Geometry Nodes_.

Comment: I was hoping that I can somehow sync the curve vertices locations (x,y) with the pixels on the depthmap.

Then I could extrude them 20mm (full white at depthmap location) down to 0mm (black).

Comment: Hm, I guess you would have to read the X/Y positions of the curve points and sample the grey value of the pixel which is closest to that location. But I would have to think about it.